# Can't finish Eclipse Plug-in Project Wizard when choosing RCP

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I'm trying create a RCP Application with Eclipse, but I can't get past the 'Content' screen of the New Plug-in Project Wizard.

When I select 'yes' for "Rich Client Application, Would you like to create a rich client application" it disables the Next and the Finish Button.

I first thought it is due to my target platform which is Eclipse 3.2, but changing that doesn't make a difference.

On the top of the screen only one task is displayed (now warnings about missing or incompatible information):  Enter the data required to generate the plug-in

My Eclipse Version is 3.5

Any ideas?

Since it was asked. A screenshot can be found here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/jensschauder/4535101973/

Comment: Can you please post some screenshots? I cant reproduce your situation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a longshot, but did you try running eclipse with the "-clean" command line argument? It sometimes solves wierd issues like this one.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling eclipse ... should have tried clean before that